# How to get cursor position (x,y) in EditText android

Tags: android

How do I get the cursor position x,y in an `EditText` in Android? (where x is the line# and y is the column#)

Comment: What do you mean by (x,y) in reference to a cursor?  (Line#,Column#)?

Comment: Yes!I want get cursor (Line#,Column#).You can help me?

Answer (score 48):

```
int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
Layout layout = editText.getLayout();
int line = layout.getLineForOffset(pos);
int baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
int ascent = layout.getLineAscent(line);
float x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(pos);
float y = baseline + ascent;
```

and there you get the x, y positions in pixels of the cursor.

Comment: This was a huge help as I am working on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036816/custom-rotated-edittext-view-with-working-selection-cursor-location-etc

Answer (score 4):

You can find the current selection's Line Number and Column like this:

```
// Get the current selection's line number
int line = edittext.getLayout().getLineForOffset(edittext.getSelectionStart());

// Find the index for the start of the selected line. Subtract that from the current selection's index
int column = edittext.getSelectionStart() - edittext.getLayout().getLineStart(line);
```