# Custom rotated EditText view with working selection, cursor location, etc

Tags: android, android-edittext, rotation, mongolian-vertical-script

#### What I want to do

I want to make a rotated and flipped EditText view that has all of the properties of a normal EditText view.

#### My problem

I have successfully made (with much help from SO users) a custom EditText view that is both rotated and flipped. This was done by overriding the onDraw method. However, the cursor and highlighting are gone and a longtouch event still indicates the original text position. Basically, the view was redrawn but the touch events were not.

How do I get the touch events, highlighting, and cursor to also be rotated and flipped?

#### What I have read

[EditText scale with selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201331/edittext-scale-with-selection) (A similar problem but not quite the same.)

[How to make a custom Edittext,so that it will look like as 45 degree rotated in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105207/how-to-make-a-custom-edittext-so-that-it-will-look-like-as-45-degree-rotated-in) (@CommonsWare noted for one solution that addition work would need to be done with touch events. What is that work?)

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html (Helpful, but I don't understand how to apply it in this situation.)

#### What I have tried

I made a custom view that extends EditText. In it overrode the onDraw method to rotate and flip the canvas. I overrode onMeasure to make the view have the right dimensions for the layout.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MongolEditText extends EditText {

// Constructors
public MongolEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
public MongolEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
public MongolEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

// This class requires the mirrored Mongolian font to be in the assets/fonts folder
private void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            "fonts/MongolChagaanMirrored.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
    textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

    canvas.save();

    canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
    canvas.rotate(90);
    canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
    canvas.scale(1, -1);

    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

    getLayout().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
}
```

There is nothing special for the layout xml.

(Update) This question is another attempt at it but in the end I couldn't get it to work: [Does invalidateDrawable() need to be overridden in addition to onDraw()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479326/does-invalidatedrawable-need-to-be-overridden-in-addition-to-ondraw)

#### Further explanation

In case you are wondering why in the world I want to rotate and flip an EditText view, here is the reason. Traditional Mongolian is written vertically in left to right columns. In combination with a vertically mirrored Mongolian font, rotating the text 90 degrees clockwise and flipping it produces readable output with correct line wrapping.

This is not an obscure or isolated problem. There are millions of users of traditional Mongolian but very few Android apps. Of these, I haven't found any that are open source. If I can get this to work, I want to make the code available to other developers.

#### Where I am looking now

(update)

I was thinking about creating a custom view (that extends `View`) from scratch to create something like a `TextView`. This `TextView` could be updated from apps to act like an `EditText` view. In this case I would only need to rotate the text 90 degrees with a normal font but not flip it. However, I would have to do my own line wrapping.

However, after reading @Chitrang's answer I think I can do something similar by just extending a TextView. Then I can avoid the trouble of doing my own line wrapping.

Picture Update

[image]

Mongolian is written from top to bottom and left to right. Right now I am using this key pad to move a cursor around the text, but I would like to be able to touch the screen to move the cursor to a position.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the picture of your current result and expected result? Have you heard about a pictures speaks more than a thousand words! :)
I love Mongolian beef jerky but I cannot get your point of view of how it is used to be written... :)

Comment: Rotation won't help you because EditText->TextView is initialized with the width height before rotation. I am looking into TextView code and experimenting :)

Comment: @AZ_ I appreciate your interest. I added a screenshot above. Although eventually I would like to get something more comprehensive, right now I would be satisfied if I could just touch a word and have the cursor appear there (even if the "cursor" means just adding the "|" character to a text string). You don't need to use Mongolian. Try rotating one line of English text with either a TextView or EditText and then get touch events to work with it.

Comment: Yeah listen bro, You are just rotating the view of EditText but if you go to the class and see the start end and bounds of EditText they will remain the same. so It is just drawing vertical, in memory is still the horizontal. There is a method setMovementMethod see this one and as they have added support RTL language you have to add support for vertical layout from extending TextView. see onTouch it's where cursor get bounds and appear on screen.

Comment: I agree with @AZ the edittext is just rotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

I ended up developing a vertical script [`MongolEditText`](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library#mongoledittext) from scratch. It is available as a part of [`mongol-library`](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library).

Here it is being used with two different third party keyboards.

[image]

#### Old answer

This is still a work in progress so I won't mark this as solved yet, but let me post what I have so far. It does most of what I wanted to do. Basically, I'm using TextView rather than EditText because EditText was doing to many strange things when rotated.

I have an unblinking cursor that responds to touch events but highlighting is still not supported. Here is the code:

```
public class MongolTextView extends TextView {

    private TextPaint textPaint;
    private Paint cursorPaint = new Paint();
    private boolean mCursorIsVisible;
    private CursorTouchLocationListener listener;

    // Naming is based on pre-rotated/mirrored values
    private float mCursorBaseY;
    private float mCursorBottomY;
    private float mCursorAscentY; // This is a negative number
    private float mCursorX;
    
    private static final float CURSOR_THICKNESS = 2f; 

    // Constructors
    public MongolTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MongolTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MongolTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // This class requires the mirrored Mongolian font to be in the assets/fonts folder
    private void init() {
        //Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
        //      "fonts/ChimeeWhiteMirrored.ttf");
        //setTypeface(tf);
        
        // Use the above commented code is using a single font in another application 
        Typeface tf = FontCache.get(SettingsActivity.FONT_DEFAULT, getContext());
        if(tf != null) {
            setTypeface(tf);
        }

        this.mCursorIsVisible = true;

        cursorPaint.setStrokeWidth(CURSOR_THICKNESS);
        cursorPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // TODO should be same as text color
        
    }

    // This interface may be deleted if touch functionality is not needed
    public interface CursorTouchLocationListener {

        /**
         * Returns the touch location to be used for the cursor so you can update the insert
         * location in a text string.
         * 
         * @param glyphIndex
         *            You will need to translate glyphIndex into a Unicode index if you are using a
         *            Unicode string.
         */
        public void onCursorTouchLocationChanged(int glyphIndex);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // swap the height and width
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

        canvas.save();

        // flip and rotate the canvas
        canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
        canvas.rotate(90);
        canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
        canvas.scale(1, -1);
        canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

        // draw the cursor
        if (mCursorIsVisible) {
            canvas.drawLine(mCursorX, mCursorBottomY, mCursorX, mCursorBaseY + mCursorAscentY,
                    cursorPaint);
        }

        getLayout().draw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }

    public void showCursor(boolean visible) {
        mCursorIsVisible = visible;
        this.invalidate();
        // TODO make the cursor blink
    }
    
    public void setCursorColor(int color) {
        cursorPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void setCursorLocation(int characterOffset) {
        
        Layout layout = this.getLayout();
        
        if (layout!=null){
            
            try {
                // This method is giving a lot of crashes so just surrounding with 
                // try catch for now
                
                int line = layout.getLineForOffset(characterOffset);
                mCursorX = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(characterOffset);
                mCursorBaseY = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
                mCursorBottomY = layout.getLineBottom(line);
                mCursorAscentY = layout.getLineAscent(line);
                
                this.invalidate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public class InputWindowTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            Layout layout = ((TextView) view).getLayout();

            // swapping x and y for touch events
            int y = (int) event.getX();
            int x = (int) event.getY();

            if (layout != null) {

                int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

                mCursorX = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(offset);
                mCursorBaseY = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
                mCursorBottomY = layout.getLineBottom(line);
                mCursorAscentY = layout.getLineAscent(line);
                //mCursorHeightY = layout.getLineTop(line);

                view.invalidate();
                
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1000);
                    listener.onCursorTouchLocationChanged(offset);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                    // notify the host activity of the new cursor location
                    
                    break;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    public void setCursorTouchLocationListener(CursorTouchLocationListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Feel free to add your own answer if you have something better or make a comment if you have something to add for improving this (adding highlighting, getting the cursor to blink, etc.). The most recent version of this code should be on [github](https://github.com/suragch/Chimee/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/chimee/MongolTextView.java).

Answer (score 3):

Tried to get the partial solution with minor changes, check if that's you want.

**1)** Set android:gravity="top|left" in your edittext declaration inside xml.

**2)** Noticed that without **super** method call inside onDraw method, not able to **show cursor**.
So I called,

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
```

instead,

```
getLayout().draw(canvas);
```

**3)** For **touch events**, I tried to swap x and y coordinates.
So that you can have cursor as per touch event.(Just tried and it was working, got lucky :) )

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    event.setLocation(event.getY(), event.getX());
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment this line inside onDraw method, for exact touch event(Found by trial and error).

```
canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
```

**4)** I could not do any thing about highlighting or **selecting** text.

**?) Another Solution :** If you think that, some how you get RTL language support
work on edittext then you just need to rotate it. But unfortunately its not working properly with android.
Reference : [How to handle RTL languages on pre 4.2 versions of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android)
and [Android setting with TextView for Hebrew text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302221/android-setting-with-textview-for-hebrew-text/6302325#6302325)

Comment: I couldn't get the edit text to work (the text kept walking off the screen as I typed and returning when I pressed enter), but your `onTouchEvent` method with the switched x and y REALLY helped me. Right now I am trying to do something similar with a TextView's touch events.

Comment: I still haven't completely solved the problem yet, but your answer helped me get past the major hurdle of handling touch events. I didn't have enough points to give you the bounty when you answered before but I do now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An attribute is there for the EditText for rotation . It is is simple and also easy to use.It might help you I think.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are much more simplier. Everything you need is already buit-in View class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)
A bit more complicated solution if previous one would not works for you by some reason is:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html
It also using for rotation of views (but animated in most cases however you could use it with zero transition duration).

Please let me know in the case you have some additional questions (guess no - there is self-explaing method and class).

Rotating just a canvas - you rotating only image on the screen. setRotation also handles all events, layout flow etc so it should works just fine in your case!

Hope it would helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:hint="Refreshing time in ms" />
```