# Resizing rotated child view in custom ViewGroup subclass

Tags: android, rotation, resize, subclass, mongolian-vertical-script

**Background**

I have a custom `ViewGroup` subclass that rotates and mirrors its child view. The purpose for this is to correctly [display traditional Mongolian text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544714/how-do-you-make-a-vertical-text-uilabel-and-uitextview-for-ios-in-swift).

I could put anything is this `ViewGroup`, but for my current project I am putting an `EditText` in it. ([I was never successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036816/custom-rotated-edittext-view-with-working-selection-cursor-location-etc) in just rotating and mirroring the `EditText` directly. However, wrapping it in this custom view group does work.)

**Problem**

My problem is that when I try to resize the `ViewGroup` programmatically, its child view is not getting resized properly along with it. I would like the `EditText` to match the size of the parent `ViewGroup` so that it appears to be a single view.

[**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

I made a new project to show the problem. The button increases the width of the ViewGroup (shown in red). The images show the project start (with everything working fine) and two width increments. The `EditText` is white and is not getting resized even though the width and height are set to `match_parent`

[image]

The full project code is below.

*MongolViewGroup.java* (Custom ViewGroup that rotates and mirrors its content)

```
public class MongolViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private int angle = 90;
    private final Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Rect viewRectRotated = new Rect();
    private final RectF tempRectF1 = new RectF();
    private final RectF tempRectF2 = new RectF();
    private final float[] viewTouchPoint = new float[2];
    private final float[] childTouchPoint = new float[2];
    private boolean angleChanged = true;

    public MongolViewGroup(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MongolViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public View getView() {
        return getChildAt(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final View view = getView();
        if (view != null) {
            measureChild(view, heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(view.getMeasuredHeight(), widthMeasureSpec),
                    resolveSize(view.getMeasuredWidth(), heightMeasureSpec));
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if (angleChanged) {
            final RectF layoutRect = tempRectF1;
            final RectF layoutRectRotated = tempRectF2;
            layoutRect.set(0, 0, right - left, bottom - top);
            rotateMatrix.setRotate(angle, layoutRect.centerX(), layoutRect.centerY());
            rotateMatrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            rotateMatrix.mapRect(layoutRectRotated, layoutRect);
            layoutRectRotated.round(viewRectRotated);
            angleChanged = false;
        }
        final View view = getView();
        if (view != null) {
            view.layout(viewRectRotated.left, viewRectRotated.top, viewRectRotated.right,
                    viewRectRotated.bottom);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(-angle, getWidth() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f);
        canvas.scale(-1, 1);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {
        invalidate();
        return super.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        viewTouchPoint[0] = event.getX();
        viewTouchPoint[1] = event.getY();
        rotateMatrix.mapPoints(childTouchPoint, viewTouchPoint);
        event.setLocation(childTouchPoint[0], childTouchPoint[1]);
        boolean result = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        event.setLocation(viewTouchPoint[0], viewTouchPoint[1]);
        return result;
    }

}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MongolViewGroup viewGroup;
    EditText editText;
    int newWidth = 300;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewGroup = (MongolViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.viewGroup);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View view) {

        newWidth += 200;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewGroup.getLayoutParams();
        params.width=newWidth;
        viewGroup.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mongolviewgrouptest.MainActivity">

    <com.example.mongolviewgrouptest.MongolViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/viewGroup"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    </com.example.mongolviewgrouptest.MongolViewGroup>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're not recalculating `viewRectRotated` for your EditText when the
  ViewGroup's `onLayout(...)` method is called again.
- Since `angleChanged` is set to false (and never changes) after your ViewGroups first layout, then the part that calculates the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` values for your EditText
  is skipped any time after the first time when your ViewGroup
  requestsLayout (when you change its height or width).
- As such, your EditText is still laid out with the same `left`,`right`,`top`
  and `bottom` values it was initially laid out with.

Do away with the `angleChanged` and it should work just fine. Like so:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    final RectF layoutRect = tempRectF1;
    final RectF layoutRectRotated = tempRectF2;
    layoutRect.set(0, 0, right - left, bottom - top);
    rotateMatrix.setRotate(angle, layoutRect.centerX(), layoutRect.centerY());
    rotateMatrix.postScale(-1, 1);
    rotateMatrix.mapRect(layoutRectRotated, layoutRect);
    layoutRectRotated.round(viewRectRotated);
    final View view = getView();
    if (view != null) {
        view.layout(viewRectRotated.left, viewRectRotated.top, viewRectRotated.right,
                viewRectRotated.bottom);
    }
}
```

I've tested this and it works just fine this way.

If you need `angleChanged` for any reason, then just make sure it's changed back to `true` inside your ViewGroup's `onMeasure` method so that `viewRectRotated` is recalculated again. However I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: This definitely and clearly solved the problem. Thank you very much! I can't award the bounty this early but I will later.